# Ошибка при работе таймера на dataEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Есть код **`ui`** и логики:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TRd-y_mYmHWmwXz7Z-mDB-mrtYiqutg0/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qggoUxzg2QVrIOmXSNTFOcb2Pba8nR-I/view?usp=sharing

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/jxc2JZObIgpYKQ

В ней `dataEdit` работает как таймер, если таймер истекает вылезает уведомление. Но, даже если таймер не истек все ровно вылезет вот такое уведомление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которое скорее всего исходит от нижнего `dataEdit` но, изменение его названия не привело к результату.

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `UI_lke2.1.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick первая ссылка на скачивание UI_lke2.1.ui

Comment: @S.Nick скинул гугл диск т.к файл слишком большой

Comment: @S.Nick добавил новую ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, которые надо изменить в **main.py**.

Я опубликую модуль **ui_lke2.ui** во втором ответе. 
Изменения в нем сделаны только на странице 'Дополнительные параметры'
и только в части имен объектов для `lineEdit` и `dateEdit`.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QDateTime, QDate

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg


class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        print(values, '\n', scale, '\n', spacing)
        return [datetime.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_q1329659.ini'


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("ui_lke2.ui", self)

        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_2
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete)
        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd_2)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete_2)
        # Сохранить данные из таблицы tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonSave)
        # Создания графиков (Ph,Fe, CO2)
        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.buttonChart_Ph)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.check_date)


        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26),
                                 QtCore.QTime(15, 12, 33))
            )
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self._date = QDate.currentDate()
        self.listLineEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        self.listDateEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDateEdit)
        
        self.load_settings()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(0, 0).dateTime()

    # Расчет времени от начального значения
    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):
        if row == 0:
            self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            for row in range(1, self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
                dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                             self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
                self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)
            return

        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                     self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
        self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonAdd(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(rowPosition)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonDelete(self):
        if self.tableWidget_2.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_2.removeRow(self.tableWidget_2.rowCount() - 1)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonAdd_2(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowPosition)
        date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        dateTime = QtCore.QDateTime().currentDateTime()
        date_from.setDateTime(dateTime)
        date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
            lambda dateTime, row=rowPosition:
            self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
        self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(rowPosition, 0, date_from)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonDelete_2(self):
        if self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_3.removeRow(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() - 1)

    # Сохранение данных из tableWidget_3
    def buttonSave(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()

        data_for_word = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                if col:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col)

                    if col == 1:
                        item = f'{float(item.text()):.0f}' if item else '0'
                    else:
                        item = item.text() if item else '0'
                else:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                        dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
                tmp.append(item)

            data_for_word.append(tmp)

        for i in data_for_word:
            print(i)

        self.buttonLoader(data_for_word)

    # Загрузка данных в шаблон Word
    def buttonLoader(self, data):
        data_for_word = []

        for item in data:
            if any(item):
                data_for_word.append({
                    "data": item[0],
                    "time": item[1],
                    "ph": item[2],
                    "ph2": item[3],
                    "fe": item[4],
                    "pm": item[5],
                    "co2": item[6],
                    "pm2": item[7],
                    "pm3": item[8]
                })

        print()
        for i in data_for_word: print(i)

        doc = DocxTemplate('test_word.docx')
        context = {
            'tbl_contents': data_for_word
        }
        doc.render(context)
        doc.save('test2.docx')

    # Построение графика Ph
    def buttonChart_Ph(self):
        data_for_word = []

        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            item_N2 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data_N2 = item_N2.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N2 else '0'
            item_N3 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 2)
            _data_N3 = item_N3.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N3 else '0'
            data_for_word.append([_data_N2, _data_N3])

        self.x, self.y = [], []
        for x, y in data_for_word:
            print(f'x={x}; y={y}')
            self.x.append(float(x))
            self.y.append(float(y))

        self.widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=2)
        self.widget.plot(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y, pen=pen, symbol='+'
        )

        w = self.findChild(PlotWidget, 'widget')

        print(f'w --> {w}')
        if w:
            w.deleteLater()
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(
            self.widget,
            0, 0, 1, 1,
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        # Фиксация размера widget
        self.widget.setFixedSize(280, 238)
        # Смена цвета графика на белый
        self.widget.setBackground('w')
        # Название графика widget
        self.widget.setTitle("Ph", color="b", size="12pt")
        # Добовляются названия осей координат
        styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "12px"}
        self.widget.setLabel("left", "Ph, ед.Ph", **styles)
        self.widget.setLabel("bottom", "Hour(H)", **styles)

        self.widget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        self.buttonChart_Fe()

    # Построение графика Fe
    def buttonChart_Fe(self):
        data_for_word = []

        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            item_N2 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data_N2 = item_N2.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N2 else '0'
            item_N3 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 4)
            _data_N3 = item_N3.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N3 else '0'
            data_for_word.append([_data_N2, _data_N3])

        self.x, self.y = [], []
        for x, y in data_for_word:
            print(f'x={x}; y={y}')
            self.x.append(float(x))
            self.y.append(float(y))

        self.widget_2 = pg.PlotWidget()
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 255, 111), width=2)
        self.widget_2.plot(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y, pen=pen, symbol='+'
        )

        w = self.findChild(PlotWidget, 'widget')

        print(f'w --> {w}')
        if w:
            w.deleteLater()
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(
            self.widget_2,
            0, 0, 1, 1,
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        # Фиксация размера widget
        self.widget_2.setFixedSize(280, 238)
        # Смена цвета графика на белый
        self.widget_2.setBackground('w')
        # Название графика widget
        self.widget_2.setTitle("Fe", color="b", size="12pt")
        # Добовляются названия осей координат
        styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "12px"}
        self.widget_2.setLabel("left", "C(Fe общ.), мг/дм3", **styles)
        self.widget_2.setLabel("bottom", "Hour(H)", **styles)

        self.widget_2.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        self.buttonChart_CO2()


    # Построение графика CO2
    def buttonChart_CO2(self):
        data_for_word = []

        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            item_N2 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data_N2 = item_N2.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N2 else '0'
            item_N3 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 6)
            _data_N3 = item_N3.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N3 else '0'
            data_for_word.append([_data_N2, _data_N3])

        self.x, self.y = [], []
        for x, y in data_for_word:
            print(f'x={x}; y={y}')
            self.x.append(float(x))
            self.y.append(float(y))

        self.widget_3 = pg.PlotWidget()
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 0, 255), width=2)
        self.widget_3.plot(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y, pen=pen, symbol='+'
        )

        w = self.findChild(PlotWidget, 'widget')

        print(f'w --> {w}')
        if w:
            w.deleteLater()
        self.gridLayout_11.addWidget(
            self.widget_3,
            0, 0, 1, 1,
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        # Фиксация размера widget
        self.widget_3.setFixedSize(280, 238)
        # Смена цвета графика на белый
        self.widget_3.setBackground('w')
        # Название графика widget
        self.widget_3.setTitle("CO2", color="b", size="12pt")
        # Добовляются названия осей координат
        styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "12px"}
        self.widget_3.setLabel("left", "C(CO2), мг/дм3", **styles)
        self.widget_3.setLabel("bottom", "Hour(H)", **styles)

        self.widget_3.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        self.buttonChart_PhFe()

    # Построение графиков Ph и Fe
    def buttonChart_PhFe(self):
        data_for_word = []
        data_for_word_2 = []

        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            item_N2 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data_N2 = item_N2.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N2 else '0'
            item_N3 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 2)
            _data_N3 = item_N3.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N3 else '0'
            data_for_word.append([_data_N2, _data_N3])

            item_N5 = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 4)
            _data_N5 = item_N5.data(Qt.DisplayRole) if item_N5 else '0'
            data_for_word_2.append([_data_N2, _data_N5])

        print(f'data_for_word   = {data_for_word}')
        print(f'data_for_word_2 = {data_for_word_2}')

        self.x, self.y = [], []
        for x, y in data_for_word:
            print(f'x={x}; y={y}')
            self.x.append(float(x))
            self.y.append(float(y))
        self.widget_4 = pg.PlotWidget()
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=2)
        self.widget_4.plot(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y, pen=pen, symbol='+'
        )
        w = self.findChild(PlotWidget, 'widget')
        if w: w.deleteLater()

        self.gridLayout_12.addWidget(
            self.widget_4,
            0, 0, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.widget_4.setFixedSize(280, 238)
        self.widget_4.setBackground('w')
        self.widget_4.setTitle("Ph / Fe", color="b", size="12pt")
        styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "12px"}
        self.widget_4.setLabel("left", "Ph, ед.Ph / C(Fe общ.), мг/дм3", **styles)
        self.widget_4.setLabel("bottom", "Hour(H)", **styles)
        self.widget_4.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        self.x, self.y = [], []
        for x, y in data_for_word_2:
            print(f'x={x}; y={y}')
            self.x.append(float(x))
            self.y.append(float(y))

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 255, 111), width=2)
        self.widget_4.plot(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y, pen=pen, symbol='+'
        )
# ??? 
        ''' ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        self._date = QDate.currentDate()
        self.listLineEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        self.listDateEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDateEdit)
        self.load_settings()
        '''

# !!!  lineEdit_dop_xxx <---> dateEdit_dop_xxx
    def check_date(self):
        self.x_y()
        listLineEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        _dict = {}
        for lineEdit in listLineEdit:
            obj = lineEdit.objectName()

#            if obj[0:9] == 'lineEdit_':
            if obj[0:13] == 'lineEdit_dop_':                       # +++       
            
#                key = obj[9:]  # lineEdit_3 --> '3'
                key = obj[13:]  # lineEdit_dop_3 --> '3'           # +++
                
                _dict[key] = lineEdit.text()
        #print(_dict)

# !!!  lineEdit_dop_xxx <---> dateEdit_dop_xxx
        listDateEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDateEdit)
        for dateEdit in listDateEdit:
            if dateEdit.objectName()[0:13] == 'dateEdit_dop_':     # +++
                # ---->
                if self._date >= dateEdit.date():
#                    key = dateEdit.objectName()[9:]
                    key = dateEdit.objectName()[13:]               # +++
                    msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
                    msgBox.setWindowTitle("ВНИМАНИЕ")
                    msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                    msgBox.setText(
                        'Пришло время, делайте что-нибудь!<br>'
                        f'Дата окончания: {dateEdit.date().toString("dd:MM:yyyy")}<br>'
                        f'Информация    : {_dict[key]}<br>'
                    )
                    msgBox.move(self.x, self.y)
                    self.y += 100        # 150
                    msgBox.show()

    def x_y(self):
        self.x = self.pos().x() + 650    # + 650
        self.y = self.pos().y()

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('Geometry', self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())

        for lineEdit in self.listLineEdit:
            try:                                                   # +++
                obj = lineEdit.objectName()
                settings.setValue(obj, lineEdit.text())
            except:                                                # +++
                pass                                               # +++ 

        for dateEdit in self.listDateEdit:
            obj = dateEdit.objectName()
            settings.setValue(obj, dateEdit.date())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)
        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        for lineEdit in self.listLineEdit:
            obj = lineEdit.objectName()
            lineEdit.setText(settings.value(obj, ""))

        for dateEdit in self.listDateEdit:
            obj = dateEdit.objectName()
            _date = settings.value(obj, QDate.currentDate())
            dateEdit.setDate(_date)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Windows")
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10))
    ex = Widget()
    ex.setWindowTitle("SAFTD version alfa 0.00.30")
    ex.setFixedSize(640, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ ОТВЕТА.

Внимание, чтобы все корректно работало, для всплывающих сообщений:

1.Все объекты должны иметь `objectName`.

2.Встроке `lineEdit` и `dateEdit` имена объектов должны соответствовать
следующим правилам:

- для первой строки `'lineEdit_dop_1'` <---> `'dateEdit_dop_1'`
- для второй строки `'lineEdit_dop_2'` <---> `'dateEdit_dop_2'`
- и т.д.

**ui_lke2.ui** часть 1 (строки 1 - 480)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <author>KB ORBIT SOFTWARE by Alexandrov Andrey Sergeevich</author>
 <class>SAFTD</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="SAFTD">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>590</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>1</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Основные параметры</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
          <property name="title">
           <string>Текстовые данные</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
           <item row="11" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_6"/>
           </item>
           <item row="15" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_8"/>
           </item>
           <item row="13" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_7"/>
           </item>
           <item row="5" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
           </item>
           <item row="14" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Конец проведения испытаний</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="3" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
           </item>
           <item row="6" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Дата заявки</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="4" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Номер заявки</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="9" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_5"/>
           </item>
           <item row="12" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Начало проведения испытаний</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="2" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Дата протокола</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="7" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4"/>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
           </item>
           <item row="8" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Обьект испытания, ориентация</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Номер протокола</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="10" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Маркировка</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Сохранение файла</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
             <item row="3" column="0">
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_11"/>
             </item>
             <item row="2" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Имя сохраняемого файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Директория сохранения файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_10"/>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>...</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
             <item row="5" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Сохранить как...</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="4" column="0">
              <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Экспорт файла</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
             <item row="5" column="0">
              <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>(Не выбранно)</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>PDF</string>
                </property>
               </item>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="4" column="0">
              <widget class="Line" name="line">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_12"/>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton_2">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>...</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
             <item row="2" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_13">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Имя сохраняемого файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="3" column="0">
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_13"/>
             </item>
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Директория сохранения файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="6" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Экспортировать как...</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Дополнительные параментры</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_7">
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_4">
          <property name="title">
           <string>Запись дополнительных данных</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_9">
           <item row="0" column="2">
            <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_19"/>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Загрузить/обновить данные</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="2">
            <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Установить общую дату окончания срока действия</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="1" rowspan="2">
            <widget class="Line" name="line_5">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Отключить проверку даты</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_6">
          <item row="5" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_3"/>
          </item>
          <item row="7" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_4"/>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_2"/>
          </item>
          <item row="17" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_9"/>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_15">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Весы электронные HR-250А, зав. № 6А7602252</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="11" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_6"/>
          </item>
          <item row="13" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_7"/>
          </item>
          <item row="9" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_5"/>
          </item>
          <item row="15" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_8"/>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_14">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Весы лабораторные МТ 1,5В1ЖА-0/НК(0,01), 2012 г</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="4" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_16">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Преобразователь ионометрический И-510, 2017 г</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="8" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_18">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Штангенциркуль цифровой ШЦЦ-11-250, 2014 г</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="6" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_17">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Электрод стеклянный лабораторный комбинированный ЭСЛК-01.7 2017 г</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="14" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_21">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Термостат 3 жидкостный ВТ25-2 серии МАСТЕР</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="10" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_19">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Термостат 1 жидкостный ВТ25-2 серии МАСТЕР</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="12" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_20">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Термостат 2 жидкостный ВТ25-2 серии МАСТЕР</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_dop_1"/>
          </item>
          <item row="16" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_30">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Термостат 4 жидкостный ВТ25-2 серии МАСТЕР</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_32">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="4" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_34">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="6" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_33">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_35">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="8" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_36">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="10" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_37">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="12" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_38">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="14" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_39">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="16" column="1">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_40">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Срок действия </string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_1">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true"/>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_2"/>
          </item>
          <item row="5" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_3"/>
          </item>
          <item row="7" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_4"/>
          </item>
          <item row="9" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_5"/>
          </item>
          <item row="11" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_6"/>
          </item>
          <item row="13" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_7"/>
          </item>
          <item row="15" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_8"/>
          </item>
          <item row="17" column="1">
           <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_dop_9"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ ОТВЕТА 2.

**ui_lke2.ui** часть 2 (строки 481 - до конца)

```
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_5">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Таблица &quot;Информационные данные&quot;</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_6">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Таблица &quot;Исходные условия&quot;, &quot;Итоговые результаты&quot;</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_17">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_9">
          <property name="title">
           <string>Таблица &quot;Исходные условия&quot;</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_20">
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
             <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
              <number>160</number>
             </attribute>
             <row>
              <property name="text">
               <string>1</string>
              </property>
             </row>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Модельная среда</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Условия подачи газа</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Температура, °С</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Объем раствора, 
л
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>pH исх.,
ед. pH
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Конц. СО2,
мг/дм3
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Конц. О2,
 %  
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Количество образцов,
шт
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Размер образца, 
× 10-3 М 
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_10">
          <property name="title">
           <string>Таблица &quot;Итоговые результаты&quot;</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_19">
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_2">
             <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
              <number>160</number>
             </attribute>
             <row>
              <property name="text">
               <string>1</string>
              </property>
             </row>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Маркировка</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Марка стали</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Вес до испытания</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Вес с продуктами коррозии</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Потеря массы,
×10-3 кг
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Потеря массы </string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Вес после снятия
продуктов коррозии
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Потеря массы,
 ×10-3 кг
</string>
              </property>
             </column>
             <column>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Скорость коррозии </string>
              </property>
             </column>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_18">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Добавить строку</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="0" column="1">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Удалить строку</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_7">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Таблица &quot;Результаты в ходе проведения испытаний&quot;</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_22">
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_21">
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget_2">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QTabWidget{
    Width: 280px;
    Heigth: 238px;
}</string>
            </property>
            <property name="currentIndex">
             <number>3</number>
            </property>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_8">
             <attribute name="title">
              <string>График &quot;Ph&quot;</string>
             </attribute>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_24">
              <item row="0" column="0">
               <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_8">
                <item row="0" column="0">
                 <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true"/>
                </item>
               </layout>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_9">
             <attribute name="title">
              <string>График &quot;Fe&quot;</string>
             </attribute>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_25">
              <item row="0" column="0">
               <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_10">
                <item row="0" column="0">
                 <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true"/>
                </item>
               </layout>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_10">
             <attribute name="title">
              <string>График &quot;CO2&quot;</string>
             </attribute>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_26">
              <item row="0" column="0">
               <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_11">
                <item row="0" column="0">
                 <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true"/>
                </item>
               </layout>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
             <attribute name="title">
              <string>Ph/Fe</string>
             </attribute>
             <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_13">
              <item row="0" column="0">
               <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_12">
                <item row="0" column="0">
                 <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_4" native="true"/>
                </item>
               </layout>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_11">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Настройки таблицы</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_23">
             <item row="6" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_71">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Директория сохранения файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="4" column="0">
              <widget class="Line" name="line_6">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="9" column="0">
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_53"/>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Добавить</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_69">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Добавить строку</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="2" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_70">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Удалить строку</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="3" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_10">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Удалить</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="8" column="0">
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_72">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Имя сохраняемого файла</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="11" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_11">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Просмотреть график</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="7" column="0">
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_52"/>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton_5">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>...</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
             <item row="10" column="0">
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_12">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Сохранить график</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_3">
          <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
           <number>160</number>
          </attribute>
          <row>
           <property name="text">
            <string>1</string>
           </property>
          </row>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Дата </string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Общее время, час</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string> pH,
ед. pH
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>погрешность ±Δ,
ед. pH 
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>С(Fe общ.),
мг/дм3
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>погрешность ±Δ,
 мг/дм3
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>С(СО2),
мг/дм3
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>погрешность ±Δ,
мг/дм3 
</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </column>
          <column>
           <property name="text">
            <string>погрешность ±Δ,</string>
           </property>
          </column>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <property name="text">
            <string>1</string>
           </property>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="3">
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </item>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]